# Adding event tracking to site for PDF/Microsoft Word downloads

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, analytics, dom-events

I am having some difficulty setting up event tracking. I have a website where people can download PDFs and Word docs of various content. I inserted the event tracking like so:

```
<a href=files/8399039122.pdf onClick='_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'downloads', 
'all', 'nofilter']);' >File #1</a>

<a href=files/8329384939.doc onClick='_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'downloads',
 'all', 'nofilter']);' >File #2</a>
```

However, after four days data is still not showing up on my analytics profile. Did I install this wrong? Also, do I need to add the `_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'downloads', 'all', nofilter]);'` to the analytics script in the header of my page?

Comment: Have you set up event tracking properly, like described here in the first section?
http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/eventTrackerGuide.html

Comment: I believe so. I followed the guidelines of that page when adding the tracking. The code above shows how I inserted the event tracking into my files. However, it still does not seem to be working properly.

Comment: Just to clarify: The above code is on a Website, and not in the markup of a Word-document, right?

Comment: Yes, both are on the website.

Comment: Not necessary to put `target="_blank". I have this type of tracking all my site without it. Here is Google's documentation on it: http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/eventTrackerGuide.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it's your use of single quotes (not nested properly). Try this:

```
<a href="files/8399039122.pdf" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'downloads', 'all', 'nofilter']);" >File #1</a>

<a href="files/8329384939.doc" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'downloads', 'all', 'nofilter']);" >File #2</a>
```

Wrap the entire `onClick` in double quotes. And, the path to your links (`href`) should be quoted as well.

To delay the onclick without using target="blank"

```
<a href="pdfs/my-file.pdf" onclick="var that=this;_gaq.push(['_trackEvent,'Download','PDF',this.href]);setTimeout(function(){location.href=that.href;},200);return false;">Download my file</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to resolve this issue is to add `target="_blank"` to the `<a>` tag:

```
<a href="files/2117802037.pdf" onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'downloads', 'all', 'nofilter']);" target="_blank">File #1</a>
<a href="files/8329384939.doc" onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'downloads', 'all', 'nofilter']);" target="_blank">File #2</a>
```

Comment: Not necessary to put `target="_blank". I have this type of tracking all my site without it. Here is Google's documentation on it: http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/eventTrackerGuide.html